# flash data is not working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

**in controller**

```
if($this->email->send()) 
    {
       $this->session->keep_flashdata("msg", "<div class='alert alert-error' style='background: rgba(22, 111, 24, 0.84); color: #fff;'>
                <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                <strong>Sucess..!</strong> We sent a activation link to " .$email. ". Please Activate your account. 
            </div>");   
        redirect('Home/clients');
    }
```

**in veiw**

```
<?php
   if($this->session->flashdata("msg"))
   {
     echo $this->session->flashdata("msg"); 
   }
?>
```

but after redirecting flashdata is not printing any msg.
please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$this->session->keep_flashdata` use `$this->session->set_flashdata`

**Also don't forget to load library**

```
 $this->load->library('session'); 
 $this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: welcome..) if you think code is working then you can accept the answer